# stub performance.now() using Sinon.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, sinon, qunit, ember-qunit

I am writing unit tests in Ember-qunit. I want to set a custom value on performance.now.

I tried `sinon.stub(performance,'now', 60000);` but this didn't work. I get `TypeError: stub(obj, 'meth', fn) has been removed.`

how do i stub performance.now() using sinon.js?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what your third argument (`60000`) is supposed to be as I am not familiar with `performance.now()`, but that's not a valid call to `Sinon.stub()` ([there is no 3rd parameter](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v9.0.1/stubs/)). Per the documentation though, you should be able to capture the stub function and then call a method on it to indicate the desired return value:

```
const stub = sinon.stub(performance, 'now');
stub.returns(60000);
```

Then, when the stub is called, you should get:

```
console.log( stub() );  // 60000
```

You can see this functionality in this [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/d7g0nb2q/).

Answer (score 1):

create a global object like:

```
global.performance = {
   now() {
    return <returning_value>; // use Date.now() or any value
};
```

Now you can access `performance.now()`